# Extracting string using MID: VBA RunTime Error 424:Object Required

Tags: excel, vba, runtime

I am using Windows 7 with Office 2013 to use Mid to extract parts of strings, depending on a condition. I am getting RunTime Error 424 for the following code:

```
RW = 1
Set c = ActiveSheet.Cells(6, 3)
While Not IsEmpty(c.Offset(RW, 0).Value)
c.Offset(RW, 3).Text = Mid(c.Offset(RW, 0).Text, 7, 2) ' Getting error on this line

If (Mid(c.Offset(RW, 0).Text, 3, 1) = "/") Then
Set c.Offset(RW, 1).Text = Mid(c.Offset(RW, 0).Text, 1, 2)
Set c.Offset(RW, 2).Text = Mid(c.Offset(RW, 0).Text, 4, 2)
ElseIf (Mid(c.Offset(RW, 0).Text, 3, 1) = "-") Then
Set c.Offset(RW, 1).Text = Mid(c.Offset(RW, 0).Text, 4, 2)
Set c.Offset(RW, 2).Text = Mid(c.Offset(RW, 0).Text, 1, 2)
End If
```

Any help on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **Text** property is *read-only.*

Use the **Value** property instead.